# Excel: Calculating GPAs with XLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making an Excel spreadsheet to calculate grade-point averages (GPAs). In column A, I have the course names; in column B, the corresponding numbers of credits; and in column C, the letter grades.

```
Course I     4.00      A
Course II    4.00      A
Course III   4.00      B
Course IV    4.00      B
```

I have the grade system on a separate sheet with the letter grades in column A and their corresponding grade points in column B.

```
A     4.00
A–    3.67
B+    3.33
B     3.00
B–    2.67
C+    2.33
C     2.00
D     1.00
F     0.00
S     —
AU    —
I     —
W     —
NGR   —
```

In the simplest case, I calculate GPA as the ratio of the sum of the products of the credits and grade points to the sum of the credits. In the example above, that would be (4.00*4.00+4.00*4.00+4.00*3.00+4.00*3.00)/(4.00+4.00+4.00+4.00). In Excel, I can make a column D that has the weighted grade points: `=B1*XLOOKUP(C1,Grades,GradePoints)`, where Grades and GradePoints are A1:A9 and B1:B9, respectively, on Sheet 2. Each cell in column D takes the grade from column C, looks up the corresponding grade points, and multiplies by the number of credits. Then I can sum column D (`=SUM(D1:D4)`) and divide it by the number of credits (`=SUM(B1:B4)`), and voilà, we have a GPA.

### BUT…

I have a problem when there’s an S (satisfactory), a W (withdrawn), an I (incomplete), or other designations that don’t have grade points. Let’s replace the first example with this:

```
Course I     4.00     A
Course II    0.50     S
Course III   4.00     A
Course IV    4.00     B
Course V     4.00     B
```

When I’m calculating the grade points, I want to exclude course II. Naturally, I would want to use `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`, but I can’t figure out what the criteria would be to sum *only* the credits that have a corresponding grade in the named range Grades. If I have `=ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C1,Grades))`, I get `TRUE` or `FALSE` appropriately, but I don’t know how to use that in `SUMIF(S)`. I have also tried using `INDEX/MATCH` without success. For the grade points in column D, I could have `XLOOKUP` return zero if the grade isn’t in the named range Grades, e.g., `=B2*XLOOKUP(C2,Grades,GradePoints,0)` would return zero since S is not in Grades. Finally, I don’t actually want to have an explicit column D or hidden cells either. I just want to show the GPA. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @S. W., you mean to say that in Sheet 1 you have course & related marks and you want to calculate Grade/GPA,, based on Table in Sheet 2,, if yes confirm through comments . Considering the grade Table in Sheet 2,, you need to redraw and include `S, AU, I` & others !!

Comment: **Cont,,** also [edit] your post & add some screen shot and expected output , help us to fix it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then:

If you have `XLOOKUP` then you probably have the `FILTER` function also.  In which case you can use the following:

*Note that I used Tables and Structured References, but you can change to regular addressing if you please*

```
GPA:  =SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(Grades[Credit],COUNTIF(gradeSystem[Grade],Grades[GP])),
         XLOOKUP(FILTER(Grades[GP],COUNTIF(gradeSystem[Grade],Grades[GP])),gradeSystem[Grade],gradeSystem[GP]))/
         SUM(FILTER(Grades[Credit],COUNTIF(gradeSystem[Grade],Grades[GP])))
```

Note that, for the letter grades without gradepoints, I excluded them from the `GradeSystem` table.  If they **MUST** be included in the table, then just change the whole column range reference to the appropriate partial column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

*Excel* by default removes non-numeric entries from an average, so if you had ten entries, all numeric, it calculates AVERAGE as SUM(x1:x10)/10 .

*However*, if entry at x10 were `W` ("Withdrawn"), rather than a number, AVERAGE defaults to SUM(x1:x9)/9 , rather than including the NAN (not a number) entry. Keep your records with mixed numbers and letters and it should do what you want.

[image: Calc example of Average]

The example above is actually done in LibreOffice *Calc*, but *Excel* should behave the same.

You can also use a lookup to change letters to numbers, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help, but I'm afraid this isn't what I am trying to do. I want to calculate a GPA as discussed in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

*Below shown method solves the problem:*

**:Caveat:**

*Since OP has not provide adequate data, therefore I've used some sample data to solve the issue.*

*The used formula is an alternative of `XLOOKUP` and works with any version of Excel.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `C80`:

  `=SUM(C$66:C$79)`
- Formula in cell `D66`:

  ```
  =IF(OR(ISBLANK(C66),ISBLANK(B66)),0,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B66,Sheet2!$F$66:$F$78,0)),0,C66*INDEX(Sheet2!$G$66:$G$78,MATCH(B66,Sheet2!$F$66:$F$78,0))))
  ```

*Fill it down.*

- Formula in cell `D80`:

  `=SUM(D$66:D$79)`
- In `C82` enter this `=C80` and in `C83` is `=D80`.
- Final Formula in cell `C84`:

  `=IF(C$82=0," - ",C$83/C$82)`

***O***r you may use this formula also.

```
=IF(OR(C$80=0,D$80=0)," - ",D$80/C$80)
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write an answer. I really appreciate it. I think your solution works if I exclude the credits for classes that don't have a letter grade. I made a column E and wrote in E66: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C66),ISBLANK(B66)),0,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B66,Grades,0)),0,C66))`. Then I filled the formula down and summed the range in E80. Then I changed C83 to `=E80`. This does work, but I would prefer not to have columns D and E in the spreadsheet. That is, I just want one cell to compute everything.

Comment: @S.W.,, I've use two sheets since you have written that *grade system on a separate sheet*,, and it's not a issue if you are shifting data from `F` to `E` ,, check the second last row,, it has a formula skips ,, process in C82 & C83,,, in your sample data class has Letter Grade,, and every one has use Letter Grade,,, the used method is popular practice among professionals. And the best part is that the shown method works with all versions of Excel. Glad to help U,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(I:I,H:H,C1:C5),""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Scott Craner,, I found that it should be an array formula,, especially when source data range is at different location I:I,, or H:H may read other value,, good move is H1:H14,,, !

Comment: Thank you, but since GPA is a weighted average, that would only work if all graded courses had the same number of credits. For example, if you had an A in a five-credit course and a B in a four-credit course, that formula would incorrectly calculate the GPA as 3.5 instead of 3.56.